# Entity Data Model Wizard Crashes (PostgreSQL)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I am installed `EntityFramework6.Npgsql` through nuget. I am trying to add EntityDataModel but everytime it crashes after this screen:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. In fact there were 2 issues.

1) Crash when adding new connection in wizard screen

Fix : Add the data connection in the Server Explorer. Then it works fine.

2) Crash while adding data connection in Server Explorer as well as Wizard screen.

Fix : Remove Postgres SQL extention. Restart VS. Add Postgres Sql Extension. Restart VS. Done.

Hope this solution helps.

Also after adding everything, extensions, packages etc. while doing CRUD operations if it fails then maybe you have not included the below configurations in the app.config or web.config file. Try adding it.

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
  <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely covered by https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1445, the fix will be released with the next version of Npgsql.

In the meantime, the workaround is simply to first add your database in the Server Explorer and only then to go through the wizard.

Comment: project nodes -> Add -> New Item ->Data -> EF Entity Data Model ->EF Designer from database ->CRASH

Comment: I am not getting crash on clicking 'New Connection."  I am not able to reach there in the first place

Comment: Any more information about the crash, any window or stack trace somewhere?